# Configure the routing for a subdomain - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, routes, subdomain

I am trying to have my web page with two sub domains, and I wonder how to configure the routing to assign different bundles to the sub domains:

```
www.my-web-page.com        =================>    DummyDemoBundle
customer.my-web-page.com   =================>    DummyCustomerBundle
```

Comment: have you seen this? <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366234/symfony2-routing-route-subdomains>

Answer (score 1):

Host routing is available since SF 2.2. Please check it out. Though I am looking for routing with subdomain as variable. This dose not seem to be supported yet.