# How to enable virtual subdomain Symfony2.1?

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

Good afternoon,

I am new to Symfony2.1 framework and trying to make virtual subdomain using .htaccess file in web/ directory.

Here is my code:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.local-biznab.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([^.]+).local-biznab.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ /var/www/biznab/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/$1?subdomain=%2 [L,QSA]
    </IfModule>
```

If there any other way doing this kindly mention.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look there [Symfony2 Routing - route subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366234/symfony2-routing-route-subdomains)

you can manage subdomains without edit the default symfony .htaccess, you just implement a listener that recognizes the subdomain from the environment information.