# How to extend Listener with controller in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I am creating a Subdomain Listener as per this discussion [Symfony2 Routing - route subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366234/symfony2-routing-route-subdomains)

So it goes to this listener and I can do the stuff I want to.

But I am not able to extend this listener with one of my controllers. listener code goes like this ...

```
namespace Acme\FrontEndBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Acme\BraPrintBundle\Controller\BraPrintController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class SubdomainListener extends BraPrintController
{
   public function onDomainParse(Event $event)
   {
       $request = $event->getRequest();
       $session = $request->getSession();
       echo $request->getHost();
       echo $this->isLoggedIn(); // defined in BraprintController
       // todo: parsing subdomain to detect country
       //do some auth stuff
       //$session->set('corporate', $request->getHost());
   }
}
```

But when I try to run it throws

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/myname/myproject/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 192
```

So when I try to debug it actully goes through extended classes but at the end in Controller its not able to deal with get().

Is there a work around to access controller functions in Listener ?

Answer (score 0):

`use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;`

`$request = Request::createFromGlobals();`

This is an alternative to interact with the HTTP request and response in an easier way.