# Symfony2 and hostname problems

Tags: symfony, subdomain, hostname

I can try to map the url the next way:

en.test.example.local | en.example.com

AND

admin.test.example.local | admin.example.com

With admin I don't have any problem working fine but, when I try to begin the uri with a variable the symfony say:
Malformed inline YAML string ({locale}{enviroment}example.{domain})...

The config is the next:

```
# web urls
example_web:
  host: {locale}{enviroment}example.{domain}
  requirements: { locale: en , enviroment: .|.\w+., domain: local|com }
  resource: "@ExampleWebBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix: /

# admin urls
example_admin:
  host: admin{enviroment}example.{domain}
  requirements: { enviroment: .|.\w+., domain: local|com }
  resource: "@ExampleAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix: /
```

If I put this:

```
# web urls
example_web:
  host: en{enviroment}example.{domain}
  requirements: { locale: en , enviroment: .|.\w+., domain: local|com }
  resource: "@ExampleWebBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix: /
```

working fine, but is a multilanguage application and I need the multilanguage by "subdomain"

Comment: I assume some, if not all, of those `.` are supposed to be literal period , if so you need to escape them with \ or encolse them in `[]` because `.` means any character when in a regex.

Comment: the problem not is "." is the format of `host: {locale}{enviroment}example.{domain}` I can see that if I begin with {locale} error throws but if not work fine.

Comment: this `host: {locale}.test.example.{domain}` `requirements: { locale:en, domain: local|com } ` not working neither

Comment: Why don't you use the `_local` parameter (http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake was very very simple :P

```
 host: "{_locale}.{enviroment}.example.{domain}"
```

missing double quotes furthermore using _locale for save in session for translate thank cheesemacfly

> Why don't you use the _local parameter (symfony.com/doc/master/book/…)?

Answer (score 0):

Well I resolved it with this information: [Symfony2 Routing - route subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366234/symfony2-routing-route-subdomains)

But if anyone know a better answer, please tell me :)