# Symfony2: locale & subdomain host pattern in routing

Tags: symfony, routes, url-routing, locale, symfony-2.2

I seem to have a missunderstanding in some aspects of the locale and subdomain pattern in Symfony2 routing.

Why doesn't this work?

```
routing_de:
    host: "dev.de.example.com" 
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing_de.yml"
    prefix: /


routing_en:
    host: "dev.en.example.com" 
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing_en.yml"
    prefix: /
```

Additionally I want to set the locale based on the subdomain. I would assume that like this would set the default locale:

```
routing_de:
    host: "dev.{_locale}.example.com" 
    resource: "@AcmeDemoBundle/Resources/config/routing_{_locale}.yml"
    requirements:
         _locale: de|en
    prefix: /
```

Even if I use the [subdomain listener described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366234/symfony2-routing-route-subdomains) (and adjust it to Symfony2.2) I can only set the _locale in the Controller. Somehow Twig gets a different locale than the Controller

```
<a href="{{ path('register', {'_locale': app.request.attributes.get('_locale')}) }} ">Register</a>
```

will return en, whilst

```
$this->getRequest()->getLocale();
```

will return my default locale set in the subdomain listener.

**EDIT 2013/04/02**
I tried to reimplement this solution (http://www.ricardclau.com/2011/09/littleweb-a-small-project-in-symfony2-chapter-1-translations/) and adjusted it for subdomains, but this seems not to work either.

Comment: well, host name matching support is available since 2.2, not 2.1

Comment: I do use the latest version. There just wasn't a tag called Symfony-2.2

Comment: I've retagged it, the [tag:symfony-2.2] tags just exists

Comment: What do you get if you dump the locale in Twig using "{{ dump(app.request.attributes.get('_locale')) }}" and how does this compare to the locale in the controller?

Comment: the twig locale is different to the one I get from the controller, like mentioned at the end of the question